# App launched due to push notification tap

Tags: c#, push-notification, windows-phone-8.1

Hello I am working on a windows phone 8.1 (RT) application and I am receiving push notifications on the app. What I want to do is, check if the user tapped on the push notification to launch the app. Because in my case suppose the push notification says "new story about Batman", now when the user taps on the push notification I need my app to navigate to the storyPage.xaml and update the view about the new story about Batman. I tried to search online but I couldn't find anything useful and I know it's possible because we all use whatsapp. when we tap on the notification about the message, that particular chat opens. I found [This Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh221550.aspx) but I don't know where to put this code. How can I achieve this? I need help Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While sending push notification, you toast xml should have launch parameters.

When the user taps or clicks the notification, the associated app is automatically launched, and so its `OnLaunched` method is invoked. If we want to determine whether the app is activated by a toast notification click, we can use the Arguments property of the `LaunchActivatedEventArgs` object that is passed to this method.

Please have a look on this blog: https://marcominerva.wordpress.com/2013/03/25/how-to-pass-arguments-to-an-app-activated-by-a-toast-notification/

Comment: thank you for the answer. However, this is if the app was launched due to toast notifications. My question targets if the app was launched using push notifications, My RESTapi fires the push notification using azure notification hub. does the same code for toast notification apply to push notification too? please help.

Comment: Push notification also creates toasts in the notification bar. So Yes.